# Retrieving data from WSDL/xsd webservice in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i used rest api for retrieving data but in this case i have soap api from where i have to get data for autofill the form, i have no idea to to use soap api in php.

Sample Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xro="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd" xmlns:iden="http://xroad.eu/xsd/identifiers" xmlns:prod="http://arireg.x-road.eu/producer/">
 <soapenv:Body>
 <prod:lihtandmed_v2>
 <prod:keha>
 <prod:ariregister_kasutajanimi>kasutajanimi</prod:ariregister_kasutajanimi>
 <prod:ariregister_parool>parool</prod:ariregister_parool>
 <prod:ariregistri_kood>70000310</prod:ariregistri_kood>
 </prod:keha>
 </prod:lihtandmed_v2>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Endpoint WSDL:
https://ariregxmlv6.rik.ee/?wsdl

XSD: http://www2.rik.ee/schemas/xtee6/arireg/live/xroad6_lihtandmed_v2.xsd

**Code:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(-1);

try {

  $options = [
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'connection_timeout' => 1
  ];

  $tcs = new SoapClient("https://ariregxmlv6.rik.ee/?wsdl",$options);
  $send = $tcs->__soapCall('lihtandmed_v2',[

      'parameters' => [
         'keha' => array(
             "ariregister_kasutajanimi" => 'secretusername',
             "ariregister_parool" => 'secretpassword',
             "ariregistri_kood" => '70000310'
           )
       ]


  ]);
      print_r($send);
  } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
      echo $exception;
  }
```

Error: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/public/index2.php:19 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('lihtandmed_v2', Array) #2 {main}

Comment: provide your code trials and error you facing

Comment: @Dev i have added